# Android: Jsoup fails to parse in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, jsoup

I've got an AsyncTask setup as following:

```
private class ParseHTMLOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Shout>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Shout> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Shout> shouts = new LinkedList<>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(params[0]);
        Elements messages = doc.select("li");

        for (int i = messages.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Element tempElement = messages.get(i);

            String username = tempElement.select(".username").text();
            String message = tempElement.select(".message").text();

            shouts.add(new Shout(R.drawable.ic_launcher, username, message);
        }

        return shouts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Shout> result) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.data = result.toArray(new Shout[result.size()]);
        adapter.addAll(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }
}
```

The problem here is: if there is anything going on in the UI, (I've tested so far with a Progressbar, a modal popup and this ProgressBarIndeterminate) this line

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(params[0]);
```

Fails to complete. It just spits this in the console:

> I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1673(100KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 965% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 8.964ms total 96.186ms
>
> I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2716(200KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(754KB) LOS objects, 1081% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 14.142ms total 210.242ms
>
> I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2219(112KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(88KB) LOS objects, 733% free, 2MB/6MB, paused 14.403ms total 167.266ms
>
> I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2194(131KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 700% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 9.194ms total 149.442ms

But, if I press the home button; it happily finishes the parsing within a few seconds.

If I comment out both of those setProgressBar... methods it parses it without a problem.

EDIT: It does finish the parsing eventually... but it takes closer to 100000ms, when  normally it would be done within max 5000ms, in addition it takes roughly 7000ms to jump into to the onPostExecute(); block, when normally it goes there way under 100ms.

Comment: If the problem is with the `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` please post its code too.

Comment: `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` is part of Android core.

Comment: Ahh my bad. Is the progress bar at least visible while the AsyncTask is running?

Comment: Yes, everything else works fine (No lag on the UI, textboxes take input etc...) it just gets stuck on the parsing.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the ProgressBar on the activity's context instead of AsyncTask's? `activityContext.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()`

Comment: It doesn't make any effect on where it is started, I tried starting it in the `onCreate();` and stopping it in the `onPostExecute();` but the result is the same.